# Novice researcher, only publishing solo, bad thing?

Tags: publications

I am currently a doctoral student in Algeria, specializing in foreign language teaching. I have noticed that my supervisor mostly publishes book chapter and always alone.
I have currently published 4 articles, in between q2 to q3 journals (we rarely publish in q1 in my country in TEFL).
I always perceived publishing alone as something negative, which indicates this researcher has a lack of social skills, is my reasoning accurate? Should I publish alone, or do I start contributing with others to enrich my CV?

Comment: One can equally well say that *not* publishing solo indicates that the researcher lacks independence. This probably has more to do with what each researcher is self-conscious about than with reality. Researchers who are self-conscious about their social skills will tend to feel that publishing solo reflects badly on them, while researchers who are self-conscious about being dependent on the contributions of others will tend to feel that *not* publishing solo reflects badly on them. Yes, it's good to collaborate with others -- not primarily for the sake of your CV, but to learn from them.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't bad to publish (and research) alone if you can sustain it, but it is probably worth developing a circle of collaborators, perhaps starting with those known to your advisor.

I would think that if your field is pedagogy then there are a lot of opportunities to work with people, especially internationally, to get ideas from other places and integrate them into a whole.

Think of it as an opportunity, though, and not a necessity. Some people work well alone and can find the ideas worth developing. But with more people involved you will get more exposure for your own ideas and more exposure to those of others that might lead to something.